# SetPluginState является устаревшим

Tags: android, flash

Делаю приложение для прослушивания музыки онлайн, реализуя через **flash**.

В Android Studio пишет: `'SetPluginState (android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState)' является устаревшим`. Есть какая-нибудь замена данному `SetPluginState`?

Comment: flash уже пару лет как не поддерживается официально в `Android`. Он и вовсе закроется через год-два. Замены, я уверен, нет, и не будет.

Comment: Понятно, буду знать